# How do I find how long a process has been running, then kill it in Ubuntu?

Tags: unix

What I want to do is to be able to find how long a process has been running, lets say over an hour, and if that process has gone over an hour, I want to kill that process all within a shell script.

I am thinking I am going to need something like ps -aux | grep scriptname and killall scriptname inotifywait just off of doing research but am unsure. I also think I will need a time function like ps -o etime = -p"$$" to find the time of process.

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach to know the EPOCH time of the creation of a pid :

```
stat -c '%Y' /proc/$$
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually used CMD and ETIMES and PID in a shell script to end processes running over 3600 seconds with a while loop and some if - then loops. Worked great. Just had to cut up some fields with the cut command and read in a variable.